Odd MonthCalendar form element issue when maximum date is selected
I am using MonthCalendar controls on a form to capture a "from" and "to" date range.
When a date is selected from the calendar control, the selected date is shown in a text box underneath.
Single-click on any of the dates and they correctly appear in the text box, except (in the supplied MRE) the maximum date (30th April 2022). I find I have to click the "30" twice on the calendar (not double-click) in order to have the date appear in the text box.
Hoping there is a reason and simple cure?
Below is the code for a minimum reproducible example (PS Version is 5.1.19041.4648):
# MAIN FORM

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = [system.Windows.Forms.Form] @{
Text = "CAL FOR SO"
Width = 255
Height = 240
StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
}

# START DATE CALENDAR CONTROL

$fromCAL = [System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar] @{
Location = "5,5"
MaxSelectionCount = 1
ShowToday = $False
ShowTodayCircle = $False
MinDate = Get-Date "01/04/2022"
MaxDate = Get-Date "30/04/2022"
}

$fromCAL.Add_DateSelected({
$fromBOX.Text = Get-Date $fromCAL.SelectionRange.start -f "dd/MM/yyyy"
})

$Form.Controls.Add($fromCAL)

# START DATE BOX
$fromBOX = [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] @{
Location = "5,174"
Size = "225,40" 
text = ""
}

$Form.Controls.Add($fromBOX)

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$Form.ShowDialog()


i'm not able to replicate, am i missing something? https://imgur.com/a/wLuxzUe

@SantiagoSquarzon our corp web proxy is blocking images from imgur.com, sorry. I appreciate you testing though.


You seem to have hit a bug in .NET Framework that therefore affects Windows PowerShell, which has since been fixed in .NET (Core) and therefore also in PowerShell (Core) 7: clicking on the maximum date (the latest selectable date) unexpectedly does not fire the DateSelected event.
The workaround - which is also the better approach in general - is to subscribe to the DateChanged rather than the DateSelected event: the latter only fires in response to mouse clicks, whereas the former fires in response to a date change by any method (mouse click, keyboard, programmatic change).
Therefore, using a streamlined version of your code:
# MAIN FORM

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = [system.Windows.Forms.Form] @{
  Text          = "CAL FOR SO"
  Width         = 255
  Height        = 240
  StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
}

# START DATE CALENDAR CONTROL

$fromCAL = [System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar] @{
  Location          = "5,5"
  MaxSelectionCount = 1
  ShowToday         = $False
  ShowTodayCircle   = $False
  MinDate           = '2022-04-01' 
  MaxDate           = '2022-04-30'
}

# START DATE BOX
$fromBOX = [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox] @{
  Location = "5,174"
  Size     = "225,40" 
  text     = ""
}

# NOTE THE USE OF DateChanged RATHER THAN DateSelected.
$fromCAL.Add_DateChanged({
  $fromBOX.Text = '{0:dd/MM/yyyy}' -f $fromCAL.SelectionRange.Start
})

# Initially select the min. date (by default, the max. date is selected).
# This programmtic date change will also trigger the 'DateChanged' event and 
# fill the text box accordingly.
$fromCal.SelectionStart = $fromCal.MinDate

$Form.Controls.AddRange(@($fromCAL, $fromBOX))
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$Form.ShowDialog()

Note:

Get-Date calls aren't required, and it's better not to rely on culture-specific data date strings; thus, the above uses culture-neutral 'yyyy-MM-dd' strings instead.

Similarly, when formatting the selected date as a string for display in the text box, it is sufficient to use -f, the format operator, as shown.

The initially selected date is set to the minimum date (by default, it is the maximum). Since the DateChange event also fires in response to programmatic date changes, the text box is properly initialized. If you want to start with the maximum date, you can temporarily change to a different date and then change it back
($fromCal.SelectionStart = $fromCal.MinDate; $fromCal.SelectionStart = $fromCal.MaxDate).



Thank you, I've re-worked my Get-Date heavy GUI to eliminate them completely. And I've updated my Powershell notes with details and examples. I don't always code for maximum efficiency but this is firmly in the 'you're doing dates wrong' category so you have moved my Powershell skills forward an important step. I needed those dates in 3 different formats, one for an SQL query, another for using in a filename and the last for GUI text-box. There is now a lot less WTF-ery going on. I understand my own script better. Very cool.

I'm glad to hear it, @Doofus; my pleasure.
